# How to find the distance between the li and the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Actually i m converting HTML to JSON

I m having the html like this:

```
<div class="treeprofit" id="divTreeViewIncomeDetails" style="height: auto;">
        <li><span class="fa fa-folder-open highlight" id="3" onmouseover="visibleLink('3', 'Incomes', '0')" onmouseout="hideLink('3')"><span onclick="GetTreeViewChartOfAccountsByParam('3', 'Incomes')">Incomes </span><span class="closingbalance">INR 50.00Dr </span></span>
            <ul>
                <ul>
                    <li><span class="fa fa-file chartwidth" id="84" onmouseover="visibleLink('84', 'Sales A/c', '1')" onmouseout="hideLink('84')" onclick="ViewLedgerMsg(84)"><span onclick="GetTreeViewChartOfAccountsByParam('84', 'Sales A/c')">Sales A/c </span><span class="closingbalance">INR 50.00Dr </span></span></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li><span class="fa fa-folder-open chartwidth" id="98" onmouseover="visibleLink('98', 'Indirect Income', '1')" onmouseout="hideLink('98')"><span onclick="GetTreeViewChartOfAccountsByParam('98', 'Indirect Income')">Indirect Income </span><span class="closingbalance">INR 0.00Cr </span></span>
                        <ul>
                            <ul>
                                <li><span class="fa fa-file chartwidth" id="99" onmouseover="visibleLink('99', 'Realized Exchange Gain', '2')" onmouseout="hideLink('99')" onclick="ViewLedgerMsg(99)"><span onclick="GetTreeViewChartOfAccountsByParam('99', 'Realized Exchange Gain')">Realized Exchange Gain </span><span class="closingbalance">INR 0.00Cr </span></span></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul>
                                <li><span class="fa fa-file chartwidth" id="122" onmouseover="visibleLink('122', 'Rounding off Gain A/c', '2')" onmouseout="hideLink('122')" onclick="ViewLedgerMsg(122)"><span onclick="GetTreeViewChartOfAccountsByParam('122', 'Rounding off Gain A/c')">Rounding off Gain A/c </span><span class="closingbalance">INR 0.00Cr </span></span></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul>
                                <li><span class="fa fa-file chartwidth" id="124" onmouseover="visibleLink('124', 'Discount Received A/c', '2')" onmouseout="hideLink('124')" onclick="ViewLedgerMsg(124)"><span onclick="GetTreeViewChartOfAccountsByParam('124', 'Discount Received A/c')">Discount Received A/c </span><span class="closingbalance">INR 0.00Cr </span></span></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul>
                                <li><span class="fa fa-file chartwidth" id="140" onmouseover="visibleLink('140', 'Stock Income', '2')" onmouseout="hideLink('140')" onclick="ViewLedgerMsg(140)"><span onclick="GetTreeViewChartOfAccountsByParam('140', 'Stock Income')">Stock Income </span><span class="closingbalance">INR 0.00Cr </span></span></li>
                            </ul>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li><span class="fa fa-file chartwidth" id="134" onmouseover="visibleLink('134', 'Clearing And Forwarding Rcd', '1')" onmouseout="hideLink('134')" onclick="ViewLedgerMsg(134)"><span onclick="GetTreeViewChartOfAccountsByParam('134', 'Clearing And Forwarding Rcd')">Clearing And Forwarding Rcd </span><span class="closingbalance">INR 0.00Cr </span></span></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li><span class="fa fa-file chartwidth" id="135" onmouseover="visibleLink('135', 'Transport charges received ', '1')" onmouseout="hideLink('135')" onclick="ViewLedgerMsg(135)"><span onclick="GetTreeViewChartOfAccountsByParam('135', 'Transport charges received ')">Transport charges received  </span><span class="closingbalance">INR 0.00Cr </span></span></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li><span class="fa fa-file chartwidth" id="156" onmouseover="visibleLink('156', 'Sales Discount A/c', '1')" onmouseout="hideLink('156')" onclick="ViewLedgerMsg(156)"><span onclick="GetTreeViewChartOfAccountsByParam('156', 'Sales Discount A/c')">Sales Discount A/c </span><span class="closingbalance">INR 0.00Cr </span></span></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li><span class="fa fa-file chartwidth" id="158" onmouseover="visibleLink('158', 'Stock Income A/c', '1')" onmouseout="hideLink('158')" onclick="ViewLedgerMsg(158)"><span onclick="GetTreeViewChartOfAccountsByParam('158', 'Stock Income A/c')">Stock Income A/c </span><span class="closingbalance">INR 0.00Cr </span></span></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li><span class="fa fa-file chartwidth" id="163" onmouseover="visibleLink('163', 'Exchange Gain A/c', '1')" onmouseout="hideLink('163')" onclick="ViewLedgerMsg(163)"><span onclick="GetTreeViewChartOfAccountsByParam('163', 'Exchange Gain A/c')">Exchange Gain A/c </span><span class="closingbalance">INR 0.00Cr </span></span></li>
                </ul>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span class="fa fa-arrow-down" style="width: 100%; color: red; font-weight: 700;"><span>Net Loss </span><span class="closingbalance">14,950.00Cr</span></span></li>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.treeprofit {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border:1px solid #999;
}

    .treeprofit li span :hover {
        background-color: whitesmoke;
        border: 0px;
        color: black;
    }
    /*Color changes on MouseOver for Root Id*/
    .treeprofit li > span:hover {
        background-color: whitesmoke;
        border: 0px;
        color: black;
    }


    .treeprofit ul { 
        list-style-type: none; 
        padding-left:15px;
    }

     .treeprofit li { list-style-type: none; 

     }

        .treeprofit li :hover {

            cursor:pointer;
        }
```

i need to find the distance between the `li` and the `div`

I tried the below code but no use of it

```
var items = [];
            var inputData = $('#divTreeViewIncomeDetails').find('li > span');

            for (var i = 0; i < inputData.length; i++) {
                var position, data1, data2;
                position = inputData[i].className;
                data1 = inputData[i].children['0'].innerText.trim();
                data2 = inputData[i].children['1'].innerText.trim();
                var width = inputData[i].offsetLeft;
                var item = { position: position, data1: data1, data2: data2, width:width }
                items.push(item);
            }
```

I m getting the value in width but its not correct

**NOTE: No Changes should be made in the HMTL**

Comment: Padding or margin. Check `CTRL+SHIFT+I`

Comment: `element.offsetLeft` should return you a coordinate for each element that tells you its distance in pixels from the left of the elements parent document. You can then compare these values for two different elements to find their distance from each other, horizontally. The same can be done with `element.offsetTop` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetLeft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get a handle on all of the LI elements on the page. Loop over them and then log their left offset to the console.

```
$('li').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).prop('offsetLeft'))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the following jquery in `$(document).ready(function(){})`

**jQuery**

```
$("li").each(function(){
    alert($(this).text()+" is at a distance of "+$(this).offset().left+"px.");
});
```

Here's a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0cey3jbe/).